# Reading value with association (simple_form)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have such models:

```
class Grade < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :question_grades
end

class QuestionGrade < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :grade 
  belongs_to :question
  # it has integer :number
end
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  # it has string :label
end
```

I have a simple_form for the 'grade' model, which iterates question_grades:

```
<%= simple_form_for @grade, :url => "/homeworks/update_grade", :method => :post do |f| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :question_grades do |q| %>
  <%= q.association :question %>
  <%= q.input :number, :collection => 0..2, label: false%>
  </div>
</div>
```

This form creates an editable form for each 'question_grade', where allows visitors to edit 'number' attribute of question_grade. I also want to show a label by using the value, 'question_grade.question.label'. I created an association with 'q.association :question' but it creates an editable input form item. I want to access a value in the association. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
    <%= q.association :question %>
```

you are creating a field to edit this association, as you can see.

What do you need, is to access the `q.object`, [defined as attr_reader here](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/simple_form/form_builder.rb#L7) .

in this case, it will be your `QuestionGrade` instance.

so this:

```
    <%= q.object.question.label %>
```

may solve your problem.

Comment: How will I get the instance of QuestionGrade under 'f.simple_fields_for :question_grades'

Comment: Should be `<%= q.object.question.label %>`?

Comment: it worked after I added this: accepts_nested_attributes_for :question_grades under Grade model. Do you know why I needed this?

Comment: @TomK. no ideia. nested forms implementation is a big black role im my opinion :P